# How do i add all the elements of a list (not add elements to the list, i mean the operation of addition)

Tags: list

i am a beginner and i wanted to know this because i couldnt find and answer on youtube because the question is very similair to adding elements TO a list i wanna know how to add all the elements (the number of elements varies) of a list (math)
ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.